# can not set limit on regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function called `vatValidate`, which is used to validate VAT format of user inputs. Currently it performs validation for two countries, Austria and Italy as default case. For each, I specified the expected user input sequence for related VAT format with regular expression.

```js
function vatValidate() {
  let vatFormat;
  let countryCode = document.getElementById('countries').value;
  switch (countryCode) {
    case 'Austria':
      countryCode = 'AT';
      vatFormat = /[U]{1}[0-9]{8}/;
      break;
    default:
      countryCode = 'IT';
      vatFormat = /[0-9]{11}/;
  }
  let vatNumber = document.getElementById('pivaid').value;
  let vat = countryCode + vatNumber;
  if (vatFormat.test(vat)) {
    console.log('Correct');
  } else {
    console.log('Error');
  }
}

vatValidate()
```

If user input matches the predefined sequence, the function logs `true` else `false`. It works fine, but the problem is, that the regex code I defined, does not enforce the length of the sequence. As I have studied to do so, for instance for Austria, I have to define the regex using `^` and `$` resulting in: `/^[U]{1}[0-9]{8}$/`

Apparently this should work just fine, as I verified it in regex101.com and can be seen below:

[image: regex code verification for the Austria case]

Now the problem is, that as soon as I add `^` and `$` in my code, it won't work any longer and it just logs an error! My development environment is Laravel and this code is executed in a script tag inside a blade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved for the case of Austria with THIS REGEX expression:

```
/^[A]{1}[T]{1}[U]{1}[0-9]{8}$/
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain how this fix the issue ?

Comment: There is no need to add a cardinality to either A or T or U, just use plain letters, e.g. `ATU`.